# Avoid using JOIN with OR

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have two tables like below:

table_1

| id_1 | id_2 | num_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 20 |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 2 | b | 21 |
| 3 | c | 22 |
| 4 | d | 23 |
| 5 | e | 24 |

table_2

| id | order | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | red |
| a | apple | red |
| b | apple | red |
| 3 | apple | red |
| c | banana | yellow |
| d | banana | yellow |
| 5 | banana | yellow |

Curretly used code looks like below:

```
select
t1.id_1,
sum(t1.num_purchases) as sum_purchases,
array_agg(t2.order) as orders

from table_1 t1

left join (select id, order from table_2) t2
on t2.id = t1.id_1

group by t1.id_1
```

However, as id in table_2 comes in either id_1 or id_2, when id from table_2 comes in id_2, the rows cannot be matched. In order to correctly join the tables so that it considers both id_1 and id_2, how should the code be structured? I'd like to avoid using JOIN with OR.

Desired outcome should look like below:

| id | sum_purchases | num_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | apple,apple |
| 2 | 21 | apple |
| 3 | 22 | apple,banana |
| 4 | 23 | banana |
| 5 | 23 | banana |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with cte1 as (
select id_1,id_2,num_purchases,b.id idb,b."order" orderB,b.colour colourB,c.id idc
  ,c."order" orderC,c.colour colourC
from table_1 a
left join table_2 b on b.id=a.id_1
left join table_2 c on c.id=a.id_2
)
,cte2 as(
select  id_1,id_2,num_purchases
  ,case when orderB is null then orderC
        when orderC is null then orderB
        when orderC=orderB  then orderB
   else concat(orderB,',',orderC) 
   end ord
from cte1
)
select id_1, sum(num_purchases) as sum_purchases
   ,array_agg(ord) as orders
from cte2
group by id_1
order by id_1;
```

| id_1 | sum_purchases | orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | apple,apple |
| 2 | 21 | apple |
| 3 | 22 | apple,banana |
| 4 | 23 | banana |
| 5 | 24 | banana |

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/iS5L0hZE)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one:

```
select
t1.id_1,
sum(t1.num_purchases) as sum_purchases,
array_agg(t2.order) as orders
from table_1 t1
left join (select id, order from table_2) t2
on t2.id = (CASE WHEN t2.id IN (SELECT id_1 FROM table_1) THEN id_1 ELSE id_2 END)
group by t1.id_1
```